# Geometry: Closest Pair of Points

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseevent, points, closest

I am a bit stuck on my homework in java for this week. The problem sounds like this:
"Write a program that lets the user click on the panel to dynamically create points. Initially, the panel is empty. When a panel has two or more points, highlight the pair of closest points. Whenever a new point is created, a new pair of closest points is highlighted. Display the points using small circles and highlight the points using filled circles. (Hint: Store the points in an ArrayList)"

In the code under I have tried to make an ArrayList of the CircleMouse class, but I do not know if this is the "correct" way to do it? Also, how do I display the circles in the panel when the are in the ArrayList?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

class ClosestPairOfPoints extends JFrame {

  /** FRIE VARIABLER **/
  int x, y;

  /*** ARRAYLIST MED ALLE SIRKLENE ***/
  public ArrayList<CircleMouse> arrCircle = new ArrayList <CircleMouse>();

  public ClosestPairOfPoints() {
    /*** PANEL FOR Å HOLDE PÅ SIRKLENE ***/
    JPanel circlePanel = new JPanel();
    circlePanel.setSize(500, 400);
    circlePanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    circlePanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);

    /*** HENTER CIRCLEMOUSE KLASSEN INN ***/
    CircleMouse circleMouse = new CircleMouse();
    circlePanel.addMouseListener(circleMouse);
    circlePanel.addMouseMotionListener(circleMouse);

    /*** LEGGER PANELET INN I FRAMEN ***/
    add(circlePanel);

}

/*** CIRCLEMOTION KLASSEN ***/
class CircleMouse extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 15, 15);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClosestPairOfPoints frame = new ClosestPairOfPoints();
    frame.setTitle("Øving 1 - Oppgave 1: Closest Pair Of Points");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to make an ArrayList of the CircleMouse class

Doesn't sound quite right.  You should have an `ArrayList` of `Point`. Each time `mouseClicked` is called, you should add the `Point` from the `MouseEvent` to it, then your `paintComponent` method, you should iterate over this list and paint the "dots"

For examples...

- [putting marks on ImageIcon in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286484/putting-marks-on-imageicon-in-jlabel/14287485#14287485)
- [Multiple Rectangle Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774618/multiple-rectangle-generation/12774873#12774873)

Comment: That sounds more correct to me. Do you have any examples, or references? I will look more into the code and see if I get somewhere with it. Thanks for you suggestion!